# Create a dictionary and pass it as a map to a Java method in Robot Framework

Tags: java, robotframework

I need to pass a java.util.Map to a a test method
In the tsv file, I tried to create a dictionary like this:

```
${MYDICT} =  Create Dictionary  a  1  b  2
```

But I got the error:

> Setting variable '${MYDICT} = Create Dictionary a 1 b 2' failed: Variable name '${MYDICT} = Create Dictionary a 1 b 2' is invalid.

I declare the dictionary in the variables section like this:

```
    ${MYDICT}=  Create Dictionary   COUNTRY US  CURRENCY_CODE   USD
```

the test case is this:

```
    testCase1 run the test using ${MYDICT}
```

and the test keywords are defined like this:

```
    run the test using ${MAP}
        call java method ${MAP}
```

and the Java method is:

```
    public void CallJavaMethod(Map<String, String> map)
```

However, if I declare the dictionary in the Test keywords section, everything works fine and the Java method is called:

```
    run the test using
        ${MYDICT}=  Create Dictionary   COUNTRY US  CURRENCY_CODE   USD
        call java method ${MYDICT}
```

I do not understand why I must declare the dictionary at the point where I want to use it. What if I want to run that test case with different inputs?

**Fix** ( used what @Uri and @Brian suggested)
I try to use the "Set Suite Variable" like in this example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Collections
Suite Setup Initialize dictionary

*** Keywords ***
Initialize dictionary
    ${dict}=    Create Dictionary   COUNTRY US
    Set Suite Variable  ${dict}

*** Test cases ***
testDict
    Dictionary should contain item  ${dict} COUNTRY US
```

And the test passes successfully.

Comment: There is no dictionary in java. You will have to use hash map

Comment: Yes I know this. However I do not know how to pass a map to the java test case. I do not know how to create it in the tsv file. JRobot is made in python and it has dictionaries as key-value pair containers.

Comment: Is test case a method ?

Comment: Yes, it is a method and it has a java.util.Map argument

Comment: I've updated my answer. The problem (or _a_ problem) is that you can't call keywords in the variable table.

Answer (score 7):

> I declare the dictinary in the variables section like this:
>
> ```
> ${MYDICT}=  Create Dictionary   COUNTRY US  CURRENCY_CODE   USD
> ```

That's the problem. You can't call keywords like that in the variable section. The variable table is for defining static values.

From the robot framework user's guide section on [variable tables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table):

> Their [variable table] main disadvantages are that values
>   are always strings and they cannot be created dynamically.

If you want to create a dictionary that can be used in multiple tests, create it in a keyword and use the [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) keyword to make it available everywhere in the suite. You can call this keyword from a Suite Setup. Or, create it in a variable file.

#### Example

The following example creates a suite-level variable named `${dict}` which contains two keys. The dictionary is initialized in a suite setup. There are two simple tests to verify that the dictionary was set up properly and is accessible to both tests.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Collections
| Suite Setup | Initialize dictionary

*** Keywords ***
| Initialize dictionary
| | ${dict}= | Create Dictionary 
| | ... | COUNTRY       | US
| | ... | CURRENCY_CODE | USD
| | Set suite variable | ${dict}

*** Test cases ***
| Test A
| | Dictionary should contain item | ${dict} | COUNTRY | US

| Test B
| | Dictionary should contain item | ${dict} | CURRENCY_CODE | USD
```

Comment: I am new to robot framework. Can you give me an example on how/where to declare it and also how to use it?

Comment: @Alex: I added an example.

Comment: I try to set up the test case like you suggested but I got this error: "No keyword with name 'COUNTRY' found."

Comment: @Alex: it must not be exactly like in this question.  My guess is, you've left out the continuation characters ("...").

Comment: Yes, I forgot some TABs. I admit that I do not know how to write these tests. Seems to me a strange formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you define the line?

From the error message it looks like the line is not defined inside a keyword / test.

Instead it looks like it's defined in the variables section of a resource file, or in a variable file.

You cannot use a keyword in the variables section.

Instead, if you want the variable to be available for all the tests,  you should define the variable in the suite-setup section as a suit variable

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup     Define map

*** Keywords ***
Define Map
  ${var}=  Create Dictionary   COUNTRY US  CURRENCY_CODE   USD
  Set Suite Variable  ${MYDICT}  ${var}
```

The error that you got (no keyword COUNTRY) seems to say that you have an extra CRLF (enter) where there shouldn't be one.

The Create Dictionary keyword is deifned in the same line - and make sure to use double space (sometimes a single tab is considered as a single space instead of a double one)

Comment: Yes indeed, I defined it in the variables section. But I do not understand...${MYDICT} is a variable. It should be declared separately and be referenced from the test.